# delete from tableview with sqlite3 statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, fmdb, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row in a UITableView which is populated from a SQL database.

The sql statement I am using is from a class called `databaseHanderClass`. The method takes an integer which is the id to delete a row in the database - the primary key.

```
-(BOOL) deleteFromDatabase: (NSInteger)delete_id
{
   FMDatabase *dbHandler = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath: [Utility getDatabasePath]];
   BOOL success;
   @try 
   {
        [dbHandler open];        
        success = [dbHandler executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM inputs WHERE id=%d", delete_id];
        [dbHandler close];
   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) 
   {
       NSLog(@"fejl...%@", exception);
   }
   @finally 
   {
       return success;
   }
}
```

The method I am using for deletion in the UITableView is the following.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];            

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) 
    {
         //statement
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the following methods: **THIS SHOULD WORK**

For your database code, try:

```
-(BOOL) deleteFromDatabase: (NSInteger)delete_id
{
    FMDatabase *dbHandler = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath: [Utility getDatabasePath]];
    BOOL success = NO;

    if(![dbHandler open])
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not open DB");
        return NO; 
    }

    [dbHandler beginTransaction];
    success = [dbHandler executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM inputs WHERE id = ?", 
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:delete_id]];

    [dbHandler commit]; 
    [dbHandler close];
    return success;
}
```

For "commitEditingStyle" method, try the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      NSInteger row_number_to_be_deleted = indexPath.row;
      //call method to delete from database
      [DatabaseHandler deleteFromDatabase:row_number_to_be_deleted];

      //now, fetch all details from Database
      self.dataSource = [DatabaseHandler getAllData];
      [tableView reloadData];
}
```

For "NumberOfRowsInSection":

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataSource count];
}
```

For "canEditRowAtIndexPath":

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

For "editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath":

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Editing Style-DELETE %i", [indexPath row]);
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

For "commitEditingStyle":

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
     {
         // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
         // Delete the row from the data source
         /* This HAS to be changed by YOU */ 
         Employee* emp = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
         NSLog(@"Delete row %i", [indexPath row]);
         [DataEngine removeData:emp];
         [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     } 
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i used the method u said, [tableView reloadData] after i called my deleteFromDatabase and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths methods in commitEditingStyle method, but it crashes with the same error.

Comment: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
2012-08-27 14:54:54.643 iSalaryCalculate[4534:c07]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',reason: Invalid update:invalid number of rows in section0.The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (26) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update(26), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0inserted,1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0moved in,0moved out)

Comment: When are you calling the "deleteFromDatabase" method?

Comment: Before the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths method. I use 1 as the parameter in deleteFromDatabase and I am deleting the first row which has the is 1 of course(just for testing )

Comment: it didnt work, but at least id doesnt crash when i try to delete. and i could not call self.dateSource =[DBHandler getAllData], i my datasource is the ViewController class: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8878926/TableViewController.m

Comment: Can you comment line number `149` ? try this instead on line 149 `[self populateTable];
    [self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: that was the wrong link: here is the right one http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8878926/TableViewController.m

Comment: line 163 is the a NSLog? but i comment it out, it doesnt work

Comment: the output of         NSLog(@"Deleted %d", [dbHandler deleteFromDatabase:row_number_to_be_deleted]);
is 0, so it seems it is removing a 0 row

Comment: Hey Ravi could you possibly write the commitEditing function for me? I am stuck here and can't figure out how to use this

Comment: i figured it out haha, the pproblem was the sql query, the promary key was input_id, not id..now at least it deletes the row sometimes. and some rows it doesnt delete.

Comment: my methods takes an integer as an parameter, but yours takes and object. the one with Employee Employee* emp = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  [DataEngine removeData:emp];... so do i need to change my deleteFromDatabase method?

Comment: Whatever works for you for the database code, the implementation that I have provided is for explaining purposes. Just delete your data from your Database and the datasource. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In `commitEditingStyle`, you need to delete the data and delete the row in one go. Otherwise your table might be in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Just call your delete method in commitEditingStyle just before deleteRowAtIndexPath. This is the best of all possible ways (Voltaire).

Comment: you mean just call it like this [databaseHanderClass deleteFromDatabase: "some delete id"];?

Comment: Right. Just do it in this very same spot in 'commitEditingStyle' method. When you remove the row, the `UITableView` will look at its `datasource` immediately to check the data. If the old data is still there, it will crash.

Comment: hey mundi. I've just tried this bt it comes with an error:Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:1037
2012-08-25 23:54:10.040 iSalaryCalculate[481:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
this is what i did;InputClassDatabaseHandler *inpMethod = [[InputClassDatabaseHandler alloc]init];
inpMethod deleteFromDatabase:1];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

Comment: Looks good. Now make sure that your datasource reflects the change. Start with `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: hmm. the number of rows in a section after an update must be equal to number of rows in that section before an update, but how do i do that?

Comment: i tested this with some nslogs just to see where the program crashes, and it seems like its right after [inpMethod deleteFromDatabase:1]; which means it crashes when it hits [tableView deleteRows....]

Comment: Post your datasource methods, `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Hey Mundi. this is the numberOfSectionsInTableView, -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

Comment: this is numberOfRowsInSection- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.table_array count];
   
}

Comment: the NSMutableArray is declared in TableViewController class (.h) and used in my populateTable method: -(void) populateTable{
    
    self.table_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    InputClassDatabaseHandler *dbMethods =[[InputClassDatabaseHandler alloc]init];
    self.table_array = [dbMethods getInput];
} the getInput method returns an array with the InputClass object. (which is one class, you know :))

Comment: So, did you remove the item from `table_array`, before deleting the tableview row?

Comment: in which method should i remove the item from table_array? and how do i do that ? here is a link to my class http://db.tt/dDawrhtA

Comment: i have written t2o methods, could the be used?              NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.table_array count] - 1 inSection:0];

Comment: and this one                                             [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];